# Access Files stored as Resources using a link control

Tags: xpages

I have a group  of files (DOC, XLS, PDF) stored under Resources-Files. I want to be able to create a set of links on a form to open them. Is this possible using the link control or do I need to do something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just refer to the file name with a relative path. The following example will create a link to a PDF:

```
<xp:link escape="true" text="Download file" id="link1" value="example.pdf">
</xp:link>
```